# Website uses IP address for auth and needs it to be the same for multiple requests

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I am using TorBrowser. However one of the websites I am connecting to seems to require that the exit IP address stay consistent across multiple requests. Is there a way to constrain torbrowser to use the same relay for a given domain(*.something.com). Part of the issue might be that the sub domains are changing between requests.

It's also possible there is some other issue with torbrowser and cookies that is unrelated.

Concretely what I observe is that the website works in a normal browser and I am able to login, but on torbrowser, I am sent back to the login screen.

Comment: sub-domains aren't isolated, for example `foo.example.com` and `bar.example.com` would both be isolated under the same `example.com` circuit. so if the resources are all on the same domain then it shouldn't be related to the circuit isolation.

Answer (score 0):

This is unlikely to be related to your IP address. The Tor Browser chooses one circuit per domain. This means that one.com and another.com are likely to have different exit IP addresses. However, those circuits are kept for some time, certainly longer than you need to login. The Tor Broswer's [design document](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser/design/) (section 4.5) has some more details about it.

In my experience, logins fail mostly because:

1. JavaScript is disabled but is required to log in. You can enable it via NoScript button (blue S) in the toolbar.
2. Login via Tor isn't allowed (exit node IPs are blocked). Many pages just show you something as simple as "login failed" with no details. There isn't anything you can do about it.

You should be aware that if you login to an account via Tor that you have logged in via clearnet (without Tor) before, the information from the clearnet logins may be used to deanonymize you.